# CFT energy scale in AdS/CFT correspondence

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, duality

In the context of the AdS/CFT correspondence, the coordinate $z$ of AdS in Poincaré coordinates is often identified with an (inverse) energy scale for a CFT. I don't quite understand this identification. I tried to read different reviews to find an exact proof of this fact, with no success.

The Euclidean $AdS_{d+1}$ space in Poincaré coordinates is $\mathbb{R}^{d}\times \mathbb{R}$.
If the identification is correct, it seems to imply that at each point $z$ we have a CFT at a different energy. For instance, at $z=0$ we have a CFT in UV and at $z=+\infty$ a CFT in IR. Is this idea correct?

Can anyone clarify these two points?

Answer (score 1):

When formulated on Minkowski space, $ds^{2}_{CFT} = \eta_{\nu \mu} dx^\mu dx^{nu}$
, the vacuum is invariant under Poincare transformations, and by virtue of conformal invariance it is also in particular invariant under a rigid scale transformation $x^{\mu} \mapsto \alpha x^{\mu}$ which simultaneously rescales the energy $E \mapsto E/\alpha$.

Identifying inverse energy with the extra dimension (labelled $z$),
the most general $5$-dimensional bulk metric consistent with these symmetries is $AdS_5$ with
$$ds^2 = \frac{l^2}{z^2}\left(\eta_{\nu \mu} dx^\mu dx^{nu}+dz^2\right)$$

where the rescaled $z ∼ 1/E$ so as to express the metric in terms of one free parameter, the AdS scale $l$. A trivial change of variables, $z = l^2/r$, recasts the above metric to something akin to the metric for $AdS_5 \times S^5$.

Comment: This is not quite satisfactory. Why is $E = 1/z$? I want to understand how the $1/z$ is related to the RG energy scale of the CFT. And, what about the second point? Is it true that for each value of $z$ there is a CFT at the energy $1/z$?

Comment: @apt45 Editeed my post, is this now sufficient?

Comment: Thanks you but still it is not a proof. It would be better to show that this identification actually arises when one considers RG flows of conformal theories (at the boundary) deformed by relevant operators. I am trying to figure out this fact. Thank you anyway. So, is it true that for any $z$ we have a CFT at a given energy in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Answer (score 1):

Since energy is propotional to $1/t$ and if we think of cft as lying on the boundary of Ads space, then the cft lives on $z = 0 $ hypersurface. Then consider a local bulk process with energy $E$ then from $d\tau = (l/z)\, dt$, we would have $$E_{CFT} = \left(\frac{l}{z}\right) E$$ since $E\sim 1/t$  and if we consider $E_{CFT}$ corresponds to the coordinate $t$ or asymptotic time. Then we can see the CFT energy is propotional to the inverse of $z$.